# Security in Socket Connection

Tags: android, security, networking

I have built an Android Application which talks to another device over TCP/IP Socket (I opened a port in that device to accept request from any program). Android application will have password to access the application and the same is configured in the Device.

In this model, how to avoid man in middle attack as the port can be accessed by anyone who are in the same network? Private Key / Public Key model would be good? Or any other secure way to protect this?

Comment: Any particular reason that using an SSL or HTTPS soket would be a problem (most likely using a self-signed certificate)?  That would do the nearly all of the public/private key stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, encryption mitigates such attacks. 
Symmetric or asymmetric depends on the context, so it's up to you to decide.

Careful with the open port, it might make you vulnerable to network attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you use TLS with public/private key for authentication. You need to authenticate the endpoints of the communication to avoid man-in-the-middle attack. In the real world certificates must be signed by a Certification Authority. In general only the server is authenticated by the client but in some cases the server might also need to authenticate the client and then it requests a certificate.